# jupyter notebook bad interpreter error message

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to use jupyter notebook with kernel python3, but I got this error message.

```
anonymous$ jupyter notebook
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Information about python and pip installed on mac (i used pip3 to install jupyter ):

```
anonymous$ which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
anonymous$ which -a pip pip2 pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Tried to solve it with "brew update && brew upgrade jupyter" as the other post suggested but did not work. Got an error message saying that "Error: jupyter not installed".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must have installed jupyter with another package manager such as `pip`. You can try `pip uninstall jupyter` followed by `brew install jupyter`.

If you get the message:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully 
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local 
Could not symlink bin/jupyter 
Target /usr/local/bin/jupyter already exists.
```

You can try `brew link --overwrite jupyter` as suggested.

Comment: brew install jupyter just hosed my python install.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I recommend pyenv for managing python installations: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: `brew link --overwrite jupyter` worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I reinstalled jupyter notebook with pip3 and everything worked fine when I treid to lauch the notebook again.

```
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I still got the error I was able to launch Jupyter Notebook. Also upgraded pip3.

Answer (score 5):

This problem usually occurs when the kernel for jupyter notebooks is being loaded from a previous python version that might not exist anymore.

- Run `jupyter kernelspec list`. kernel.json contains the path to the python version in use. You can either change this path directly, or nuke the Jupyter install (as follows) and reinstall it.
- Remove the Jupyter folder location (on mac: `rm -rf /Users/<username>/Library/Jupyter/`)
- `brew uninstall jupyter; brew cleanup`
- If using pip and pyenv: `pip install jupyterlab` otherwise `brew install jupyter`

Comment: Deleting old kernel spec folders helped. Did not need to reinstall Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error when I was using jupyter in a virtual environment. This was when I switched from `homebrew`'s python to the OS's python3.

All I had to do was `rm /usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab` and then run `jupyter-lab`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same and I tried `$brew install jupyter` as suggested here. But it gave me this error -

```
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

As M1 Mac user this solved the issue finally -

```
arch -arm64 brew install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2020, @teresa 's solution worked for me.

I have to run pip3 to install devices, you can check which command for pip you need to use by running

```
pip -v
```

and if you get nothing, try `pip3 -v`

Depending one which one worked, enter:

```
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "pip3" installs jupyter with the same Python version in the kernel and the one being used in the notebook.

```
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```